short audio drop outs after upgrade to Nvidia RTX 3060, Ubuntu 24.04
In Ubuntu 24.04 I used a Nvidia GTX 1060, now after replacing with a Nvidia RTX 3060 I experience constant and repeated short audio drop outs, caused by almost anything that happens in Ubuntu.
I can play an audio file in VLC, stream a video from youtube in firefox, even run speaker-test in a terminal, does not matter. Often audio drops out for fraction of a second when I for example

just change between open windows, say clicking the vlc window - the ubuntu desktop - some other window - terminal - back to vlc
open any settings window, open a new tab in firefox, open Nautilus
plus sometimes there are drop outs without any input from my part

And I can switch between the cards consistently, with the old GTX 1060 no problems, with the new RTX 3060 drop outs
Connected an AV Receiver via HDMI and can see the loss of data there as well as I can hear it of course. This is unbearable. Already read many articles but do not find anything related to my problem, I do not have any crackles or things like that.
Mainboard is Asus Prime Z590-P, Cpu is Intel Core i9-11900KF
Edit #1
regarding driver:
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices reports
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00002504sv00001043sd0000881Dbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GA106 [GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate]
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-550-open - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-550 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-555-open - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-server-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-555 - third-party non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-535 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

sudo ubuntu-drivers install will pick version 555, did that several times. That driver is picked for both cards. I assume that is correct.
Edit #2
systemctl --user status pipewire.service
● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-07-20 15:43:36 CEST; 2h 5min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 1782 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18902)
     Memory: 10.2M (peak: 11.4M)
        CPU: 216ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
             └─1782 /usr/bin/pipewire

Jul 20 15:43:36 RAY systemd[1752]: Started pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service.
Jul 20 15:43:37 RAY pipewire[1782]: mod.jackdbus-detect: Failed to receive jackdbus reply: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.jackaudio.service was not provided by any .service files

Now through Apps / Software & Drivers / Additional Drivers switched to the noveau driver, restarted the system, looks good - no audio drop outs with the noveau driver so far. But thats not really a solution in the long term...
???

You make no mention of the NVIDIA driver. Are you sure they both use the same driver? That may be an issue.

I mentioned ubuntu-drivers, now edited the question to clarify

Is pipewire your audio backend?

Yes it is pipewire, that is pretty much left untouched since installing Ubuntu 24.04, providing more info on that, getting an error message there?

Did you do anything to get ubuntu-drivers to work (launchpad bug 2037004)?  Even with graphics-drivers PPA, a currently updated 24.04 does not list 550 or 555, but does list 545 for my 3080. I am running 555 but had to do a direct install (everything is working fine).

As to why I get drivers 555, I think that is because I installed cuda, which as of now is version 12.5 which will then somehow enable driver version 555 I guess. I did not do anything otherwise

555.52.04 is the version in the graphics-drivers PPA. I recommend totally separating CUDA from system -- it's just an app, so don't let it take over drivers or sprinkle files into system areas like /bin or /lib (use .run script options for this). It is possible the standard repos have the proper audio linkup for the Nvidia High Definition Audio Controller.

Well I now installed nvidia-driver-535 through Apps / Additional Drivers, but no change, audio drop outs all over

After hours and hours of digging and trying I finally found the core problem.
PCIE needs to be at Gen2 for the graphics card in Bios, ONLY THEN sound is working without any drop outs. 100% reproducible.
So to recap my hardware

Asus Prime Z590-P, Bios version 1803 as well as latest version 2002
ASUS GeForce Dual RTX 3060 12GB V2

The precise setting in Bios is Advanced / System Agent (SA) Configuration / PCI Express Configuration. There PCIEX16_1 Link Speed MUST be set to Gen2, as setting to Gen3 or Gen4 or Auto WILL PRODUCE audio drop outs. This is true for any Nvidia driver, tested many.
Unbelievable, just Unbelievable.
And to top it all off, another thing I found: As I stated I have hdmi connected to an AV receiver. This reports by default as a screen device with 3840 x 2160 pixels. With latest nvidia driver 555 at this default setting there is no sound at all!! ONLY when I set the screen resolution to 1920 x 1080 do I get ANY sound through!!

After hours of research I stumbled on your post and wow, thank you infinitely. For me downgrading to gen 3 was enough to fix the problem (RTX 3050, driver version 550, kubuntu 24.04).
